# How does one arrive at this conclusion?

Tags: calculus, continuity

I can't figure out how to arrive at the correct answer for the below question. To me there seems no intuitive reason that the given option should be the correct one.

**Question:** Let $f:  [0,10]→[10,20]$  be  a  continuous  and  twice  differentiable  function  such  that $f(0) = 10$ and $f(10) = 20$. Suppose $|f'(x)| ≤1$ for all $x∈[0,10]$. Then, the value of $f''(5)$ is

A.  $0$
B. $\frac{1}{2}\ $
C. $ 1$

D. Cannot be determined from the given information.

Now, the correct answer given here is option B, but I simply can't understand how to arrive at this answer.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Could you explain to us what you have tried so far?

Comment: Seems wrong $f(x)=10+x$ works and $f''(x)=0$.

Comment: You can't figure it out, because the "correct" answer is incorrect. Herb's right, in fact, only option A makes any sense here.

Comment: @user3733558 That makes sense. But I still don't get how can we pinpoint a single value for $f ' ' (5)$. I get it that $f(x) = 10 + x$ works for the given conditions and and for it we have $f ' ' (x)=0$ but how can we be sure that there's no function with the above properties for which  $f ' ' (5) \neq 0$.

Comment: @KritikaAgarwal you can justify that $f(x) = 10+x$ is the only possibility if you're familiar with the [mean value theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem). Pick some $x_0 \in [0,10]$ and consider what happens if $f(x_0)<10+x_0$ or if $f(x_0)>10+x_0$. In both cases, you will be able to show a contradiction with the initial condition $|f′(x)| \leqslant 1$.

Comment: My intuition is that from $f(0) = 10$ to $f(10) = 20$ the function increased by $10$ so the "average" rate of change is $1$.  But $|f'(x)| \le 1$.   I have to cite the right Intermediate value theorem or mean value theorem are something like that but if $f'(x) \le m$ then $f(x+k) \le f(x) +mk$, right... It's gotta be cause it can't jump *more* than the rate of change, right? , ao can only happen if $f'(x)$ is a constant $1$ i.e. this is straight up line with a constant slope of $1$.  If $f'(x) = 1$ a constant then $f''(x) = 0$.

Comment: Hello, @KritikaAgarwal, this question has been closed for a lack of context, but I can guide you to opening it so it continues to receive attention and answers. First request : paraphrase your comment into the question, it counts as an attempt. Second : mention the source of the question . Third , mention your background in calculus and what theorems you are aware of , and are you reading from any particular book? If you insert  these things, I put them in a reopen queue, where people see the question's improvement , vote to open it, and it gets attention again. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As herb steinberg points out in the comments, **A** is correct. We're going to use the second part of the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Second_part) here:

$$ \int_a^b f'(x) \ dx = f(b) - f(a) .$$

Given all the facts you've provided, we know

$$ \int_0^{10} f'(x) \ dx = f(10) - f(0) = 20 - 10 = 10. $$

Now, let's say there's some interval $(a,b) \subset [0,10]$ such that $f'(x) < 1 \ \forall \ x\in (a,b)$. Then, from the fact that $|f'(x)| \le 1$, we have the following:

$$ \int_0^a f'(x) \ dx \le \int_0^a 1 \ dx, $$
$$ \int_a^b f'(x) \ dx < \int_a^b 1 \ dx, $$
$$ \int_b^{10} f'(x) \ dx \le \int_b^{10} 1 \ dx. $$

Summing the two sides across the three inequalities, we have

$$ \int_0^{10} f'(x) \ dx < \int_0^{10} 1 \ dx $$
$$ \Longrightarrow \int_0^{10} f'(x) \ dx < 10 . $$

But, this violates the FTC (above), therefore our initial assumption must have been incorrect, and we must have $f'(x) \ge 1$ for all $x\in [0,10]$.

Combined with $|f'(x)| \le 1$ for all $x \in [0,10]$, we have $f'(x) = 1$ for all $x\in (0,10)$, which then implies $f''(x) = 0$ for all $x \in (0,10)$.

Comment: "This question seems not to meet the standards for the site. Instead of answering it, why not look for a good duplicate target, or help the user by posting comments suggesting improvements? [Please also read the meta announcement regarding quality standards."](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33508/enforcement-of-quality-standards?cb=1).

Answer (score 0):

As $f'(x)\le1$,

$$f(10)=f(0)+\int_0^{10}f'(x)\,dx\le10+10$$

and equality with $20$ is only possible with $f'(x)=1$. Hence $f''(x)=0.$